# jQuery On <select> Change Event Not Firing

Tags: jquery

I have the following in the header:

```
$('body').on('change', '#userFilter', function(){
   console.log('changed');
});
```

And this element is dynamically inserted on the page when a tab is clicked:

```
<select id="userFilter">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that when I change the dropdown nothing is shown in the console.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KhY8s/. Make sure you bind the event handler when `body` exists (jQuery 101). From the [jQuery **tutorial**](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Hello_jQuery): *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."*. Why does it seem no one is reading it?

Comment: Please tick the answer then :)

Comment: Just a quick note to help others who might have made the same stupid mistake - make sure you dont have an accidental duplicate id, eg if you happen to have a div with the same id as your filter, the change event is not going to fire!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Wrap it in [$(document).ready(function(){....})](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so that the html control `userFilter` is added to DOM and available for `javascript`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').on('change', '#userFilter', function(){
      console.log('changed');
   });
});
```

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code, [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: I have a TextArea inside an UpdatePanel and the above doesn't work for me for some reason :/ Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit unrelated to the OQ, if you got here because your select is not firing, make sure that at a previous time you didn't check the "Prevent this page from showing..." in the `alert()`. You'd need to close the tab and reopen that URL to get that to fire visibly again.