# Jquery select change not firing

Tags: jquery, onchange

I need to capture when a select box changes, should be simple!

```
    $('#multiid').change(function(){
    alert('Change Happened');
});
```

But it does not work, I suspected the problem is that the select box does not exist on document ready it is created only if needed, so I created it empty in HTML, populated it with code as a test but that didn't work either.

```
function buildmulti(id,name,price) {
    // build action items for action bar
    var optlist = $('<select></select>').attr('id', 'multiid').attr('name', 'multiid');
    optlist.append('<option value="0">Select Size</option>');
    $.each(option, function(index, val) {
        if(val.prodID *1  == id * 1) {
            v = val.ID;
            fprice = price * 1 + val.pricechange * 1;
            t = name + ' - ' + val.variation +  ' - ' + currency + (fprice).toFixed(2);
            optlist.append('<option value="' + v + '">' + t + '</option>');
        }
    })
    $('#addbasket').append(optlist);
};
```

it's probably another bracket out of place, but I can't find it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery On <select> Change Event Not Firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885958/jquery-on-select-change-event-not-firing)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Try

```
 $(document).on('change','#multiid',function(){
    alert('Change Happened');
});
```

As your select-box is generated from the code, so you have to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), where in place of `$(document)` you can have closest parent element.

Or

```
$(document.body).on('change','#multiid',function(){
    alert('Change Happened');
});
```

**Update:**

> Second one works fine, there is another change of selector to make it work.

```
$('#addbasket').on('change','#multiid',function(){
    alert('Change Happened');
});
```

Ideally we should use `$("#addbasket")` as it's the closest parent element [*As i have mentioned above*].

Comment: Yeah... you can use `$('body')`, Anyways Glad it helped :-)

Comment: the second one works nowadays. all other things not working. it's too much time to dig on what's changes has been made in the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
$('body').on('change', '#multiid', function() {
    // your stuff
})
```

please check `.on()` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 11):

You can fire  chnage event by these methods:

First

```
$('#selectid').change(function () {
    alert('This works');
});
```

Second

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectid', function() {
    alert('This Works');
});
```

Third

```
$(document.body).on('change','#selectid',function(){
    alert('This Works');
});
```

If this methods not working, check your jQuery working or not:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   alert('Jquery Working');
});
```

Comment: The second is best, it works in all conditions. On the first time page loaded and dynamically some changes in the page using ajax or jquery. It is work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on('change','#multiid',function(){
  // you desired code 
});
```

reference **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!

```
$('#<%= ddlstuff.ClientID %>').change(function () {
    alert('Change Happened');
     $('#<%= txtBoxToClear.ClientID %>').val('');
});
```

Comment: Note that the ID portions, ex. `<%= ddlstuff.ClientID %>` .... are specific to ASPX Razor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For me perfectly fork this code.

```
$('#dom_object_id').on('change paste keyup', function(){
    console.log($("#dom_object_id").val().length)
});
```

Key event for .on() function is "paste" to get changes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, it should work

```
$(document).on('change','#fieldid',function(){
    alert('change triggered');
});
```