# Change text font in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to change the font attribute for text in fabric.js.

Here is my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/mvprzy/szzGa/

I believe this part of the fabric script should work, but isn't:

```
var fontControl = $('font-control');
fontControl.onchange = function () {
    fabric.Text.set('fontFamily', font-control.value);
    canvas.renderAll();
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/szzGa/3//)

First of all you need to include jQuery in the jsfiddle (: After that all I did was make the `fabric.IText` a variable and change the on change function to the following based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194177/jquery-select-change-not-firing)

```
var fontControl = $('#font-control');
$(document.body).on('change', '#font-control', function () {
    text.fontFamily = fontControl.val();
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: Thanks - had not noticed that jQuery was not included, sheesh.  Had tried text as var earlier but was not going - that document.body tip did the trick.. Awesome.