# Dropdown bind onchange method in Razor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following dropdown. How can I bind the `OnChange` method to it?.

I am using Code first MVC approach. Also, how can I get the index value when binding on change method to it?

```
 <div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, "Empl")
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.DropDownList("Id", String.Empty)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery to bind on change and then get the index then .

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19194194/1817929) should take care of it..

Comment: this needs id of the dropdown , but i dont have id

Comment: "Id" is the id of the dropdown? First argument of Html.DropDownList is id. You can access its value by writing `$("#Id").val()`.

Comment: yes done...tnhnx alot man   $('#Id').change(function () {
        var a = $("#Id").val();

Comment: Can you please tell me , how can i write "Select City" over my DropDown..As per now my drop Down is blank

Comment: As far as I know, the 3rd argument of Html.DropdownList specifies the default text. So you should write something like this: 

`Html.DropdownList("Id", String.Empty, "Select City")`

Comment: You knowledge of MVC in Asp.net actualy i was stucked with  dropdowns , can you provide me help

Comment: 2nd argument must be a selectlist, you don't provide a list to dropdown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60236/discussion-between-jot-dhaliwal-and-burak-karakus).

Comment: burak plz come in chat rooom

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { onchange = "changeFunction()" })
```

That's assuming you want a blank list.

Comment: My drop down are showing values from database, they are not empty