# playing sound onchange table content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a function which will play a sound when the value of a table field changes I tried it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#hor-zebra").change(function(){ 
         document.getElementById('bflat').play()
     });
});
```

Sorry I forgot my HTML:

```
<audio id="bflat" src="timbre.mp3"></audio>

<table id="hor-zebra" class="col-6" summary="">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Ticket</th>
        <th scope="col">Puesto</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd first">
        <td class="first">A083</td>
        <td class="first">MESA 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>B064</td>
        <td>MESA 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C028</td>
        <td>MESA 5</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: And what's the issue? Add your HTML too.(in your question)

Comment: For text fields or text areas, the change event occurs when the field loses focus, after the content has been changed.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194177/jquery-select-change-not-firing), it might be applicable for you.

Comment: does it help? :
https://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/

Comment: What you really mean by " table field " td?

Comment: Vishal, yes I mean <td></td>