# Select2 Dropdown Multiple select and unselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, dropdown

I have a `select2` dropdown with 4 options code is:

```
<select id="ddlInqOn" class="InqSelect2 form-control">
  <option value="1">--All--</option>
  <option value="2">Today Date</option>
  <option value="3">Past Date</option>
  <option value="4">Feature Date</option>
</select>
```

`select2` called by this `javascript`:

```
$('.InqSelect2').select2({
  dropdownAutoWidth: 'true',
  multiple: true
});
```

I want to achieve like when I click all option then remove other options and if other option is selected then remove all option from selection.

I have tried this code:

```
$('body').on('change', '#ddlInqOn', function() {
  debugger;
  //
});
```

but the change event is not triggred so any other possibility to track change event of select2 dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given by @Nimeksha works perfectly in jsfiddle given by @ Nimeshka but in my code i cant get trigger event of change in dropdown and after searching i found solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194177/jquery-select-change-not-firing). the code is here :

```
 $(document).on('change', '.InqSelect2', function () {
        debugger;
        if (e.params.data.id == 1) {
            $(this).val(1).trigger('change');
        } else {
            values = $(this).val();
            var index = values.indexOf('1');

            if (index > -1) {
                values.splice(index, 1);
                $(this).val(values).trigger('change');
            }
        }
    });
```

i have also tried :

```
   $('body').on('change', '.InqSelect2', function () {
        debugger;
        if (e.params.data.id == 1) {
            $(this).val(1).trigger('change');
        } else {
            values = $(this).val();
            var index = values.indexOf('1');

            if (index > -1) {
                values.splice(index, 1);
                $(this).val(values).trigger('change');
            }
        }
    });
```

but it doesn't work. also by id #ddlInqOn does not work.

why above code worked with `$(document).on('change', '.InqSelect2', function () {});` worked i dont know but it works for me.

thanks again @Nimeshka

Answer (score 4):

Select2 uses the jQuery event system. So you can attach to the select2 events using the JQuery `on` method.

Then you can set the value of the select element and trigger the `change` event to update the select box.

You can do what you have asked in following way.

```
$('.InqSelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {

    if (e.params.data.id == 1){
        $(this).val(1).trigger('change');
    }else{
        values = $(this).val();
        var index = values.indexOf('1');

        if (index > -1) {
            values.splice(index, 1);
            $(this).val(values).trigger('change');
        }
    }
});
```

Note that I have used '1' as the value of --All-- option. Feel free to ask me anything if it's not clear to you.

https://jsfiddle.net/c6yrLoow/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: this function doesn't get called

Comment: what do you get? any error? and what's the version of select2 you use?

Comment: no error just cant get called the function or cant get the event called and using select2 4.0.3

Comment: You mean the change event is not triggered?

Comment: your jsfiddle is perfectly working .. thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161684/discussion-between-shine-infosoft-and-nimeshka-srimal).