# DataTables: add .select event to second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have table with lots of data so am using jquery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). Now i have a select dropdown inside the table: on the first page the select dropdown with script is working, on the second page the alert is not showing when I select the data from the dropdown. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya001/z1k6n72r/1/).

code:

```js
$("#example").dataTable();

$(".opt_value").on("change", function() {
  alert("===11===");
  alert($('option:selected', this).val());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sites</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
          <option value="">STATUS</option>
          <option value="aa">aa</option>
          <option value="bb">bbb</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <select class="opt_value" name="opt">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="aa">aa</option>
            <option value="bb">bbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

can anyone please suggest how to do thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery select change not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194177/jquery-select-change-not-firing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should attach the event to the document for [dynamic added objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript):

```
jQuery(document).on("change",".opt_value", function(){
     alert("===11===");
     ...
});
```

Here the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1k6n72r/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your jQuery code with the below code, and event handler should be on `document`

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '.opt_value', function() {
    alert('===11===');
    alert( $('option:selected', this).val() );                
});
```

or, you could also use

```
jQuery('body').on('change', '.opt_value', function() {
    alert('===11===');
    alert( $('option:selected', this).val() );                
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You attach the change event handler **before** rows of second page have been created. Therefore, their changing is not listened. So, you have to attach the event handler function for all table and use [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

```
$("#example").dataTable();
$("#example").on("change", ".opt_value", function() {
  alert("===11===");
  alert($('option:selected', this).val());
});
```