# How to retain multiple form values in JavaScript after reloading a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk, javascript-objects, dom-events

Below is how I tried to retain the form values using JavaScript, but it is not working:

```
<form action="" method="Post" onload="saveData();">
<Label>1. What is your favourite browser?</Label>
<select id="browserValue">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
    <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<Label>2. What is your favourite food group?</Label>
<select id="foodValue">
    <option value="Meats/Alternatives">Meats/Alternatives</option>
    <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    <option value="Dairy Products">Dairy Products</option>
    <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
    <option value="Grains">Grains</option>
    <option value="Confections (Junk Food)">Confections (Junk Food)</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<Label>3. What is your favourite game genre?</Label>
<select id="gameValue">

    <option value="FPS">First Person Shooter (Ex: Halo, Call of Duty)</option>
    <option value="TPS">Third Person Shooter (Ex: Ghost Recon, Gear of War)</option>
    <option value="Puzzle">Puzzle (Ex: Sudoku, Minesweeper)</option>
    <option value="Sim">Simulation (Ex: Minecraft, SimCity)</option>
    <option value="Other">Other (Please specify the genre)</option>
   </select>

<br>
<br>
<input type="button"  value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
function saveData(){
    var q1 = document.getElementById("browserValue").onChange().value;
    var a = localStorage.setItem("browsers", q1);
    var q2 = document.getElementById("foodValue").onChange().value;
    var b = localStorage.setItem("food", q2); 
    var q3 = document.getElementById("gameValue").onChange().value;
    var c = localStorage.setItem("game", q3);

   }
   document.getElementById("browserValue").value = a;
   document.getElementById("foodValue").value = b;
   document.getElementById("gameValue").value = c;  
</script>
```

How to retain multiple form values in JavaScript after reloading a web page?

Comment: I have never used this before but shouldn't you use document.getElementById("browserValue").value = localStorage.getItem("browsers") to get the value from local storage? Your variable a, b, c will go out of scope when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Yes I have done also like as you said but still it is not working @GobSmack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle and it seems to be working: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4hsxjhnd/1/

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="Post">
<Label>1. What is your favourite browser?</Label>
<select id="browserValue">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
    <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<Label>2. What is your favourite food group?</Label>
<select id="foodValue">
    <option value="Meats/Alternatives">Meats/Alternatives</option>
    <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    <option value="Dairy Products">Dairy Products</option>
    <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
    <option value="Grains">Grains</option>
    <option value="Confections (Junk Food)">Confections (Junk Food)</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<Label>3. What is your favourite game genre?</Label>
<select id="gameValue">

    <option value="FPS">First Person Shooter (Ex: Halo, Call of Duty)</option>
    <option value="TPS">Third Person Shooter (Ex: Ghost Recon, Gear of War)</option>
    <option value="Puzzle">Puzzle (Ex: Sudoku, Minesweeper)</option>
    <option value="Sim">Simulation (Ex: Minecraft, SimCity)</option>
    <option value="Other">Other (Please specify the genre)</option>
   </select>

<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="savecode()">
<input type="button" value="Reload" onclick="getcode()">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
//Script
function savecode()
{
  localStorage.setItem("browsers", $("#browserValue").val());
  localStorage.setItem("food", $("#foodValue").val());
  localStorage.setItem("game", $("#gameValue").val());
}

function getcode()
{
    alert(localStorage.getItem("browsers"));
   document.getElementById("browserValue").value = localStorage.getItem("browsers");
   document.getElementById("foodValue").value = localStorage.getItem("food");
   document.getElementById("gameValue").value = localStorage.getItem("game");  
}
```

A few things I learnt while solving this were that: onload works only with body
[see here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?29136-lt-form-onLoad-quot-quot-is-this-legal)

Also, I read about either wrapping onchange in document ready or attaching an event listener to it to trigger the event properly: 
[event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952804/onchange-event-doesnt-trigger), [ready event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885958/jquery-on-select-change-event-not-firing?lq=1)

I have modified the program slightly. If you press the reload, it will fetch the values from local storage instead of the values auto-filling on page refresh which can be easily changed. Also, I am using the submit button instead of onchange.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you your answer helped me a lot @GobSmack

Comment: @CSiva Glad I could help :)